# ASP Web App Is It Possible To Have Different BackGround Colour Depending On Which Server Hosts The App

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MCV application.  I have a working copy running off my local PC, a production copy sitting on my application server.  For quick testing of small revisions, I want a user on the other side of the office to access my local copy before I update the files on the server.  But I don't want the user to be able to confuse mypc/myapp with myserver/mypp.  To do this, I thought maybe I have some config somewhere which says: if hosted on "myserver", background colour to be black; else background colour to be red, or something.

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.

The quickest and simplest way would just be to have a key in your web.config which is set to true on your production server.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="production" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Add a new css class to your stylesheet for your development background colour

```
.development-bg {
background-color: #FF49F2;
}
```

And then at the top of your _Layout.cshtml (assuming you are using the razor view engine)

```
@{       
    if(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["production"] != "true")
    {
        ViewBag.BackgroundColorCssClass = "development-bg";   
    }
}
```

Then modify the body tag in your _Layout.cshtml

```
<body class="@ViewBag.BackgroundColorCssClass">
```

Alternatively if you didn't want to have a web.config value you could try the following

```
@{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName == "your machine name")
    {
        ViewBag.BackgroundColorCssClass = "development-bg";    
    }
}
```

Like i said there are lots of ways to do this. This way is very simple but may suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Rik - looks like a nice solution.  As it happens I also copy my web.config across during updates - one of the things I'm hoping for here is to find a solution where I don't have to change any config when copying to the live server (you always forget to do these things then your users end up with a horrible, ugly red background).  If you could throw another of your ways to do it at me, it'd be very appreciated.  My first thought was something to do with the url and some kind of "if (urlString.Contains(serverName))" evaluation?